# Question concerning subset sum problem: split into 3 equal subsets

Tags: dynamic-programming

**Task:** Given an array $arr[a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n]$ of integers, let $A = \sum\limits _{i\in \{1, 2, \dots, n\}}a_i$.  Determine whether it is possible to spit $arr[]$ into 3 subsequences of equal sum, i.e. if $s_1 =s_2 = s_3 =\dfrac{A}{3}$ where $s_1 ,s_2 , s_3$ denoted the splitted arrays.

**My thoughts:** I will first examine whether there exists some sequence of numbers that sums up to $\dfrac{A}{3}$ via dp, then I will backtrack those numbers, "throw them out" (meaning I won't consider them anymore), and proceed with the remaining numbers of the array. After doing this a second time I examine whether the numbers left sum up to $\dfrac{A}{3}$ and return true if this is the case. Even though this sounds valid to me I somehow doubt the correctness of this.

**Recurrence of DP:** $dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-a_j] \text{ OR } dp[i-1][j]$

$dp[]$ is a boolean array of dimension $n \times\dfrac{A}{3}$.

Comment: Can you detail what you mean by "backtrack those numbers"?

Comment: I don't see a question here.  We are a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question.  We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as such are unlikely to be useful to anyone else in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my solution:

```java
    boolean 3_Partition(int arr[]) {
        if (arr == null)
            return false;
        int sum = Arrays.stream(arr).sum();
        if (sum % 3 != 0)
            return false;
        int n = arr.length;
        boolean dp[][][] = new boolean[n+1][sum = sum / 3 + 1][sum];
        for (int i = 0; i < n+1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < sum; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < sum; k++) {
                    if (i == 0 ) dp[i][j][k] = false;
                    else if (j == 0) dp[i][j][k] = true;
                    else if (k == 0) dp[i][j][k] = true;
                    else  dp[i][j][k] = j >= arr[i-1] && k >= arr[i-1] ? dp[i - 1][j - arr[i-1]][k] || dp[i - 1][j][k - arr[i-1]] || dp[i - 1][j][k]
                          : j >= arr[i-1] ? dp[i - 1][j - arr[i-1]][k] || dp[i - 1][j][k]
                          : k >= arr[i-1] ? dp[i - 1][j][k - arr[i-1]] || dp[i - 1][j][k] : dp[i - 1][j][k];
                }
            }
        }
        return dp[n][sum-1][sum-1];
    }
```

Comment: We discourage code-only answers.  We're not a coding site; we're looking for answers that come with explanation, justification, concise pseudocode, and/or proofs of correctness.  You said elsewhere that your question was whether the approach outlined in the post is correct, but this doesn't appear to answer that question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the proposed algorithm is correct. It may happen that the first solve for $A/3$ picks a set of numbers that makes it impossible to split the remainder into equal halves. Consider this example:

- Given the set of numbers $\{1,1,3,3,3,4,8,10\}$, which sum to $A=3*11$
- Assume that the first DP picks $||\{1,1,3,3,3\}||_1=11$
- It is impossible to split the remaining set $\{4,8,10\}$ into equal halves.

Here's a recursive function in pseudocode instead which computes what you need in a single step:

```
bool CanBuild3EqualSums(int sumA, int sumB, int sumC, int[] numbers)
{
    if(numbers is empty)
        return sumA == sumB && sumB == sumC;
    else
        return CanBuild3EqualSums(sumA + numbers[0], sumB, sumC, numbers.WithoutFirst())
            || CanBuild3EqualSums(sumA, sumB + numbers[0], sumC, numbers.WithoutFirst())
            || CanBuild3EqualSums(sumA, sumB, sumC + numbers[0], numbers.WithoutFirst())
}
```

This is a pure function (without side-effects). Add memoization and you'll end up with a DP algorithm. Of course, there are many other ways to formulate this. There is some potential for a more efficient, practical implementation:

- You could pass the index of the next number, instead of the whole array.
- You could get rid of sumC, and compute when needed, based on sumA and sumB
- If you have small values, a bottom-up formulation might be more efficient.

Comment: thanks, but that wasn't my question: I want to know whether my solution is correct

Comment: I updated the answer with details why I think the original solution can't work in some cases.